# Divs being displayed as tables inside divs being displayed as tables

Tags: html, css

My goal was to use HTML/CSS in a way that I found similar to how Android layouts worked, but I am getting some strange rendering.

I have nested div sets that are programmed by CSS to display as tables, table-rows, and table-cells. My goal was for the inner tables to match the width of the parent table with `width:100%` but instead I get this... (see picture)

The only thing I can think of doing is making new CSS classes and assigning the inner tables to be those? (Something I would like to avoid)

[image: right side of chrome browser]

```
div.label
{
    display:table-cell;

}
div.input
{
    display:table-cell;

}
div.error
{
    display:table-cell;

}
div.inputlabel
{
    display:table-row;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding:10px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color:#6b81e2;
    width:100%;

}
div.table
{
    display:table;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding:10px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color:#ecc1ec;
    width:100%;
}


<?php 
    include('libraries/database_config.php');

    print_r($_POST);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="libraries/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <link href="libraries/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="libraries/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
        <title>New Membership</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <div class="table">
                <div class="inputlabel">
                    <div class="label">
                        <div class="table">
                            <div class="inputlabel">
                                <div class="label">
                                    First Name
                                </div>
                                <div class="input>">
                                    <input type="text" name="fname"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="error">

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="inputlabel">
                                <div class="label">
                                    Last Name
                                </div>
                                <div class="input>">
                                    <input type="text" name="lname"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="error">

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="inputlabel">
                                <div class="label">
                                    Email Address
                                </div>
                                <div class="input>">
                                    <input type="text" name="email"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="error">

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="inputlabel">
                                <div class="label">
                                    Phone Number
                                </div>
                                <div class="input>">
                                    <input type="text" name="phone"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="error">

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="inputlabel">
                                <div class="label">
                                    Street Address
                                </div>
                                <div class="input>">
                                    <input type="text" name="streetaddress"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="error">

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="inputlabel">
                    <div class="label">
                        <div class="table">
                            <div class="inputlabel">
                                <div class="label">
                                    <button type="button">Add Product</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="label">
                                    <button type="button">Add Profession</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="label">
                                    <button type="button">Add Company/Service</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="inputlabel" id="data_div">

                </div>
            </div>
        </form>



        <script type="text/javascript"/>

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note: `<link>` and `<input>` do not use or need a closing slash. Your `<script>` tag is invalid with the closing slash at the bottom and needs to be removed. In fact, you can remove everything inside the brackets except the word script.

Comment: I see this as an attempt to use a table layout without using a table for layout. This is unnecessary and there are far better means to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea; you've simply forgotten to take the **[`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin)** into consideration when accommodating for the **[box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Box_model)**. You'll need to subtract both margins from your calculated `100%` width, which can fortunately be done really easily with CSS' **[`calc()` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)**.

Bcause of your complex structure, you'll want to adjust for this offset three times, and on both sides each time, giving you a total of `6` adjustments that need to be calculated for.

As such, for `.div.table`, you're looking for `width: calc(100% - (5px * (3 * 2)))`:

```css
div.label {
  display: table-cell;
}

div.input {
  display: table-cell;
}

div.error {
  display: table-cell;
}

div.inputlabel {
  display: table-row;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #6b81e2;
  width: 100%;
}

div.table {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #ecc1ec;
  width: calc(100% - (5px * (3 * 2)));
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form action="" method="POST">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="inputlabel">
        <div class="label">
          <div class="table">
            <div class="inputlabel">
              <div class="label">
                First Name
              </div>
              <div class="input>">
                <input type="text" name="fname" />
              </div>
              <div class="error"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="inputlabel">
              <div class="label">
                Last Name
              </div>
              <div class="input>">
                <input type="text" name="lname" />
              </div>
              <div class="error"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="inputlabel">
              <div class="label">
                Email Address
              </div>
              <div class="input>">
                <input type="text" name="email" />
              </div>
              <div class="error"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="inputlabel">
              <div class="label">
                Phone Number
              </div>
              <div class="input>">
                <input type="text" name="phone" />
              </div>
              <div class="error"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="inputlabel">
              <div class="label">
                Street Address
              </div>
              <div class="input>">
                <input type="text" name="streetaddress" />
              </div>
              <div class="error"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="inputlabel">
        <div class="label">
          <div class="table">
            <div class="inputlabel">
              <div class="label">
                <button type="button">Add Product</button>
              </div>
              <div class="label">
                <button type="button">Add Profession</button>
              </div>
              <div class="label">
                <button type="button">Add Company/Service</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="inputlabel" id="data_div"></div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```